# Detecting a touch NOT on a UITextField (to make keyboard hide)

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have some UITextFields which bring the keyboard open.

My question is, how can I detect a touch on the screen that is NOT in ANY UITextField

Pseudocode of what I need:

```
if(screen is touched)
   if(touched view is NOT a UITextField)
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Or another easier way to hide the keyboard when a UITextField is not touched?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view and use `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

```
- (void)addTapGesutre {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self
                                                                             action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self keyboardDismiss];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDismiss {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, however it doesn't work for views that already detect taps (i.e. buttons). For those, I just added `[self keyboardDismiss]` to their IBActions.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the touches began method.

Look at the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:).

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

From the documentation -

> If you override this method without calling super (a common use
>   pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch
>   events, if only as stub (empty) implementations.

Comment: FYI - the question is tagged Objective-C. Answers should be posted in the appropriate language.